# Babeltrace Connection Refused

Tags: lttng, babeltrace

I'm using LTTng for live debugging. The target machine which I'm debugging has connectivity to only one other machine (say M1), which in turn has connectivity to the external world. I've started lttng-relayd on M1. M1 and my dev host can ping each other. On the target machine, I've created an lttng session as:

```
lttng create --live 100000 -U net://M1's-ipaddr
```

I've enabled filters and have started the session.

Now on my dev host (or for that matter any other machine) when I run

```
babeltrace -i lttng-live net://M1's-ipaddr
```

I get the below error:

```
Connect: Connection refused
[error] Connection failed
[warning] [Context] Cannot open_trace of format lttng-live at path net://M1's-ipaddr.
[warning] [Context] cannot open trace "net://M1's-ipaddr" for reading.
[error] opening trace "net://M1's-ipaddr" for reading.
```

I googled about it, but could not find much help. My babeltrace version is 1.4.0

Comment: `Connection refused` implies that the listener isn't running, or the port is hidden by some firewalling.  You might need a bit of (non-programming) work to solve this - you're more likely to get help on [sf] or [su] for that.

Comment: The default listening URL of the LTTng relay daemon for LTTng live connections is `tcp://localhost:5344`. If you run `babeltrace` on another host, than start the relay daemon with `lttng-relayd --live-port=tcp://0.0.0.0:5344`, for example. See http://lttng.org/man/8/lttng-relayd for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, @eepp. This indeed solved the problem.